Show HTML file in a modal Nextjs
I have an html file which kinda looks like this , it is a long one I'm just showing you a little piece of it:

<body lang=EN-US style='word-wrap:break-word'>

<div class=WordSection1>

<p align=center style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:12.0pt;
margin-left:0in;text-align:center'><b><span style='font-size:14.0pt;font-family:
"Segoe UI",sans-serif;color:#172B4D;letter-spacing:-.05pt'>&#304;stifad&#601;
&#351;&#601;rtl&#601;ri raz&#305;l&#305;q anla&#351;mas&#305;</span></b></p>


<p align=center style='margin-top:0in;margin-right:0in;margin-bottom:12.0pt;
margin-left:0in;text-align:center'><strong><span lang=AZ-LATIN
style='font-size:10.0pt;font-family:"Segoe UI",sans-serif;color:#172B4D;
letter-spacing:-.05pt'>(Xidm&#601;t &#351;&#601;rtl&#601;ri v&#601;
M&#601;xfilik siyas&#601;ti)</span></strong></p>
</div>
</body>

And I have a modal in one of my components , I need to show this html content which is basically some styled text , nothing functional in this modal.
I have tried saving this html file in my public folder or src folder. But even when i try to import the document it doesn't see it or import it. I need an easy approach to this problem

I have converted this file from word document , that's why it looks so weird

But even when i try to import the document it doesn't see it or import it this is the code we need to see - how are you 'importing' it in to the parent page?

like this :
import doc from '../../../../../public/Agreement.html';


Import inside pre tag which will execute your html if thats your goal.

One of the easiest way (as you prefer) might be React's dangerouslySetInnerHTML.
You can import your external html content as plain text, then set it into the div. Here's the sample.
function createMarkup() {
  // Read your html content here.
  return {__html: 'First &middot; Second'};
}

function MyComponent() {
  return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={createMarkup()} />;
}

https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#dangerously-setting-the-inner-html
As the name suggested, it is dangerous to do. So use it with precaution.

This should be used with extreme caution! If the HTML inside isn’t trusted (for
example, if it’s based on user data), you risk introducing an XSS
vulnerability.

